# Including module structure for testing but not for distribution

Tags: python, setuptools, tox

Consider the following package structure

```
project   # Project root
 package  # Main package that one wants to distribute
  ...     # Modules comprising the package
 mockup   # Mock up of a package structure used for testing
  ...     # Modules comprising the mock up structure
 tests    # Testing package containing unittests
  ...     # Modules comprising the unittests
 setup.py # setup script
```

How should one configure the `setup.py` script to

- include only the `package`'s source code but not the `tests` nor the `mockup` folder during distribution
- yet include the `mockup` folder when running the `tests` with tox

Presently I have the following specified; which distinguishes the package code from the testing code but does not make the `mockup` available during test execution.

```
setup(
  ...
  package = find_packages(exclude=['tests','mockup']), # Includes package code but not tests or mockup folders
  test_suite ='tests',                                 # Includes tests but not the mockup's
  ...
)
```

Specifying `mockup/**` in `MANIFEST.in` includes it in the distribution as does specifying `package_data`/`include_package_data` in `setup.py`. Perhaps Tox allows mockup structures but I'm not finding this in the documentation.

Comment: While going through the tox documentation on `usedevelop` I noticed there is also an `extras` argument. The documentation is not especially clear on how to use this but I got the impression this populated the virtual environment with further content. Perhaps this provides an alternate means of including a "mock" package ?

Comment: extras installs what is defined in the extras_require of setup.py (http://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setuptools.html#declaring-extras-optional-features-with-their-own-dependencies) - this won't help with this problem because what you need is not a package but the contents of a folder in the project.  The config option in tox could definitely explained a bit more in detail referring to extras_require.

Comment: Oh sweet so that is the optional part one sees from time to time in install instructions e.g. the `extras` in `pip install [extra]package`. I was wondering about that this morning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

tox builds a package exactly like it is specified in `setup.py` and `MANIFEST.in` by running `python setup.py sdist` for you. There is no way to build a special package for testing with tox. This would defeat the purpose of tox, which is that you test exactly the package that you want to release.

If you want to run some special tests with files/folders that should not be part of the release, but which are part of the project (so part of the project structure in which your `tox.ini` lives) I would recommend to run those tests against a development install of your project, which contains all you need. You should still test the package against your other tests, but those other tests could be done in a different tox environment.

Very simplified, in a project that contains the different test types in different folders under `tests` this could look something like that (I am writing this from a pytest user perspective - you will have to translate that to unittest - or just run your unittests like this with pytest :)):

```
[tox]
envlist = tests,mockuptests

[testenv:tests]
description = runs the "normal" tests against the installed package
deps = pytest
commands = pytest tests/normal

[testenv:mockuptests]
description = runs the "mockup" tests against an editable installation
usedevelop = True
deps = pytest
commands = pytest tests/mockup
```

On second thought I think that testing the package against the mockups should also be possible in a different way without having to put those files into the package, depending on how your tests are structured and how your testrunner does stuff. As run unittest and I don't have enough details about your project setup, I don't know how you would do this in your case.

Comment: This solved it, thank you. My apologies for the slow response I saw your post almost immediately but took some time to respond. Am I correct in understanding that  `usedevelop=True` installs the entire project via `pip install -e .`, or similar equivalent, into the testing virtual environments' site-packages ?

Comment: Glad I could help :) yes, that is correct - usedevelop installs the package in devlopment (or editable) mode.